# Write time series data into hdfs partitioned by month and day?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a program which save the time series data from `kafka` into hadoop. and I designed the directory struct like this:

```
event_data
|-2016
  |-01
    |-data01
    |-data02
    |-data03
|-2017
  |-01
    |-data01
```

Because the is a daemon task, I write a LRU-based manager to manage the opened file and close inactive file in time to avoid resource leaking, but the income data stream is not sorted by time, it's very common to open the existed file again to append new data.

I tried use `FileSystem#append()` method to open a `OutputStream` when file existed, but it run error on my hdfs cluster(Sorry, I can't offer the specific error here because it's several month ago and now I tried another solution).

Then I use another ways to achieve my goals:
Adding a sequence suffix to the file name when the same name file exists. now I have a lot of file in my hdfs. It looks very dirty.

My question is: what's the best practice for the circumstances?

Comment: HDFS isn't really designed for appending to files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that this is not a direct answer to your programming problem, but if you're open for all options rather than implement it by yourself, I'd like to share you our experiences with [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) and it's [HDFS (WebHDFS) Output Plugin](http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_webhdfs).

Fluentd is a open source, pluggable data collector and by which you can build your data pipeline easily, it'll read data from inputs, process it and then write it to the specified outputs, in your scenario, the input is `kafka` and the output is `HDFS`. What you need to do is:

- Config fluentd `input` following [fluentd kafka plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka), you'll config the `source` part with your kafka/topic info
- Enable `webhdfs` and `append` operation for your HDFS cluster, you can find how to do it following [HDFS (WebHDFS) Output Plugin](http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_webhdfs)
- Config your `match` part to write your data to `HDFS`, there's example on the plugin docs page. For partition your data by month and day, you can configure `path` parameter with time slice placeholders, something like:

  `path "/event_data/%Y/%m/data%d"`

With this option to collect your data, you can then write your mapreduce job to do ETL or whatever you like.

I don't know if this is suitable for your problem, just provide one more option here.

Comment: I'm open for any option only if it could resolve the problem. In fact, there's some details wasn't posted in my question. The messages in kafka is not a plain text, instead they are `protobuf` message, and the `timestamp` is a field in the `protobuf` message. I've not found a clear support for `protobuf` in `fluentd` yet now. Another detail is the format of the messages store in hdfs is  lines of `json` with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: You can always process/transform your data from kafka in your service and push the well-formatted data to 3rd party service(like fluentd) to take care of the process of loading data into HDFS, which makes your service focus on data transform/process only and be one of steps in your entire data pipeline. Anyway, it's your choice based on your tech stack and preference. Sorry that no clue for your bug, I just can't reproduce it.